# Is it possible to decode strings automatically using SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, unicode, sqlalchemy

Using SqlAlchemy, I have some String column that fails with

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 356: ordinal not in range(128)

because they are not Unicode.

I know that by doing my_string.decode('cp1252'), it works, but is it possible to define a method that will decode all the string returned from the database automatically.

With it, calling my_model.my_string, would be processed before return and decoded.

I looked into http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#coercing-encoded-strings-to-unicode, which seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, but I don't know where to tell SqlAlchemy to use the `CoerceUTF8` class.

Comment: Why does flask matter? Why not the DBMS you are using?

Comment: Why not have the DB-API adapter decode strings according to the connection charset?

Comment: You already found the solution. What you build there is a new type. So instead of `Column(String...)` or `Column(Unicode...)` you do `Column(CoercedString...)`.

Comment: I forogt to mention that I tried to specify the UTF-8 charset in the connection string for the database, without luck. Turn out, the problem was my database encoding wasn't uft8. @Javex, post it as the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for your comments guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found the solution. What you build there is a new type. So instead of `Column(String...)` or `Column(Unicode...)` you do `Column(CoercedString...)`.